# Ext JS 5 Button.sass error onbuild

Tags: sass, extjs5

I am trying to make my own template in Ext JS 5, I use desktop view. 
I followed this guide http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/core_concepts/theming.html Everything is clear to me; I make a new template, default scss works very well, but when I try make a Button.scss file, something like this:

```
@include extjs-button-ui(
$ui: 'team-arrow',
$background-color: red
);
```

and try to build an application by 'sencha app build' I get this error:

```
[INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
    error UbiPlatformPBX-all.scss (Line 62 of ../../../../../ext/packages/ext-theme-base/sass/etc/functions.scss: Undefined operation: "5px-null gt 0".)
   create UbiPlatformPBX-all.css
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: compass process exited with non-zero code : 1
[ERR]   at co
[ERR] m.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:72)
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 19 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/usr/local/ubipbx/wc_patryk/ubiquity-platform/extjs/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:284: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/usr/local/ubipbx/wc_patryk/ubiquity-platform/extjs/.sencha/app/sass-impl.xml:155: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/usr/local/ubipbx/wc_patryk/ubiquity-platform/extjs/.sencha/app/sass-impl.xml:176: com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: compass process exited with non-zero code : 1
```

I have no idea what the problem is, for example when I make a Panel.scss file and use this code:

```
@include extjs-panel-ui(
    $ui: 'highlight-framed',
    $ui-header-background-color: yellow,
    $ui-border-color: yellow,
    $ui-header-border-color: yellow,
    $ui-body-border-color: yellow,
    $ui-border-width: 5px,
    $ui-border-radius: 5px
);
```

everything works ok.

Comment: Can you provide the source of the extjs-panel-ui mixin?

Comment: You mean source in my app ? Now when I type extjs-button-small-ui instead of extjs-button-ui it is working...

Comment: I need the definition of the mixin (eg. `@mixin extjs-panel-ui(...) { ... }`).

Comment: it is in next answer

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, Is there any solution for this ?